# Dropwizard with atmosphere and guice integration issue

Tags: integration, guice, atmosphere, dropwizard

I'm trying to integrate together dropwizard with atmosphere and guice, I followed some internet links such as:

I have followed this guide to integrate dropwizard with atmosphere: [link](https://github.com/stakkTraze/dropwizard-atmosphere)

I have a dependency in my project for [atmosphere-guice](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.atmosphere/atmosphere-guice)

Finally, I have added a listener in my environment setup for integrating injector

```
 @Override
    public void run(final MyConfig configuration, final Environment environment) throws Exception {

// ...
        environment.servlets().addServletListeners(new GuiceServletContextListener() {
            @Override
            protected Injector getInjector() {
                return injector;
            }
        });
// ...
}
```

I have also integrated some code as shown from [dropwizard-guice](https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice):

```
// ...
final GuiceContainer container = new GuiceContainer();
modules.add(new GuiceJerseyContainerModule(container));
// ...
```

Finally, I'm adding an AbstractModule with the following declarations as the [documentation from Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-BroadcasterFactory-and-AtmosphereResourceFactory-with-2.2-and-newer#guice) describes

```
@Provides
AtmosphereResourceFactory provideAtmosphereResourceFactory(AtmosphereGuiceServlet atmosphereGuiceServlet) {
     return atmosphereGuiceServlet.framework().atmosphereFactory();
}

@Provides
BroadcasterFactory provideBroadcasterFactory(AtmosphereGuiceServlet atmosphereGuiceServlet) {
     return atmosphereGuiceServlet.framework().getBroadcasterFactory();
}
```

Now I'm trying to add an AtmosphereResourceFactory at one of my resources and I want to use it and send something to a particular user with

```
@Path("/")
public class IndexResource {

    @Inject
    private AtmosphereResourceFactory resourceFactory;


    @GET
    @Path("/{user}")
    public String sayHello(@PathParam("user") String user){
       AtmosphereResource resource = resourceFactory.find(user); // not found
       resourse.write("Some message");
    }
}
```

My problem is that this particular instance is not the same  AtmosphereResource and number of resources is zero while I have at the same time connected resources via a simple websocket client.

Has anyone faced any similar problem? How is it possible to have different AtmosphereResourceFactory instances? Shouldn't this be some short of singleton inside my app?

Thank you, let me know if additional info is required

Sorry for long description